# Why am I getting a different ouput when the variable monthly_salary is declared in the while loop versus outside?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

In python, when I include **monthly_salary** variable in the while loop I get a different output than if it is declared before the loop. When it is placed within the loop the output is 142. When it is placed before the while loop the answer is 183. Why is this?  Sorry for any mistakes - I am just starting. Thank you for any insight!

```
total_cost = 500000 #float(input())
downpayment = total_cost * .25
current_savings = 0
investment = (current_savings * .04) / 12
annual_salary = 120000 #float(input())
portion_save = .05 #float(input())
month_count = 0
semi_annual_raise = .03#float(input())


while downpayment >= current_savings:
    **monthly_salary = annual_salary / 12**
    current_savings += (portion_save*monthly_salary) + (current_savings * .04) / 12
    month_count += 1
    if month_count % 6== 0:
        annual_salary += (annual_salary*semi_annual_raise)
print(month_count, 'months')
```

Comment: when `monthly_salary` is declared inside of the while loop, it is modified in each loop so the value is changed. When it is declared outside of the loop it does not change

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Python has no variable declarations.  You have *assigned its value* inside the loop.  The reason is simple, traceable with `print` statements.

In the posted version, you change the value at the start of every loop iteration.  Since `monthly_salary` depends on `annual_salary`, and you change the latter on every loop iteration, then the former changes accordingly.

When you assign that value only once, before the loop, then it remains unchanged while you iterate through the months of your algorithm.

Comment: Hi Prune, thank you for your answer! So to confirm - it is best to assign variables that are going to be iterated upon, INSIDE the loop rather than before the loop?

Comment: It depends entirely upon how the value is supposed to be handled.  *That* tells you where it belongs.  For instance, your required down payment doesn't change throughout the program, so you set it once and leave it there.  Your savings changes every month, so you update it on every iteration.  You get a raise every year, so you change it every 12th month.  See how there's no generic rule?